# pyttsx3 python speech module throwing handling exceptions

Tags: python, python-3.x

i was trying to get audio output using pyttsx3 in python
here is the code:

```
import pyttsx3

def speak(text):
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

speak("hello world")
```

**It is throwing handling errors which i am not able to understand:**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\harshit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3_*init*_.py", line 20, in init
eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
File "C:\Users\harshit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\weakref.py", line 137, in **getitem**
o = self.datakey
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\harshit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 3, in <module>
    from comtypes.gen import SpeechLib  # comtypes
ImportError: cannot import name 'SpeechLib' from 'comtypes.gen' (C:\Users\harshit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\gen\__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\harshit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 121, in WINFUNCTYPE
    return _win_functype_cache[(restype, argtypes, flags)]
KeyError: (<class 'ctypes.HRESULT'>, (<class 'comtypes.automation.tagVARIANT'>, <class 'comtypes.automation.LP_tagVARIANT'>, <class 'ctypes.c_long'>), 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Learning/100dayscode/python/voice.py", line 132, in <module>
    speak("Hello ")
  File "D:/Learning/100dayscode/python/voice.py", line 23, in speak
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
  File "C:\Users\harshit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\harshit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\harshit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "C:\Users\harshit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\harshit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 6, in <module>
    engine = comtypes.client.CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
  File "C:\Users\harshit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 250, in CreateObject
    return _manage(obj, clsid, interface=interface)
  File "C:\Users\harshit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 188, in _manage
    obj = GetBestInterface(obj)
  File "C:\Users\harshit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 110, in GetBestInterface
    mod = GetModule(tlib)
  File "C:\Users\harshit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py", line 110, in GetModule
    mod = _CreateWrapper(tlib, pathname)
  File "C:\Users\harshit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py", line 184, in _CreateWrapper
    mod = _my_import(fullname)
  File "C:\Users\harshit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py", line 24, in _my_import
    return __import__(fullname, globals(), locals(), ['DUMMY'])
  File "C:\Users\harshit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\gen\_C866CA3A_32F7_11D2_9602_00C04F8EE628_0_5_4.py", line 365, in <module>
    ( ['out', 'retval'], POINTER(POINTER(ISpeechObjectTokens)), 'ObjectTokens' )),
  File "C:\Users\harshit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 329, in __setattr__
    self._make_methods(value)
  File "C:\Users\harshit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 698, in _make_methods
    prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(restype, *argtypes)
  File "C:\Users\harshit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 123, in WINFUNCTYPE
    class WinFunctionType(_CFuncPtr):
TypeError: item 1 in _argtypes_ passes a union by value, which is unsupported.
```

Comment: It looks like the error is from the library `pyttsx3`. I would recommend to double-check the   requirements of the library. it says that it can't import `SpeechLib` from `comtypes.gen`

Answer (score 0):

Well i figured it out.
It looks like the new version of pip have conflicts with updates.
This code worked for me

```
python -m pip install pyttsx3==2.71
```